# android update database error

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sql-update

Well I am trying to update a value in database false to true;

this is my code

```
public void updatecheck( int id){
     mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

       ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
       newValues.put("check", true);
       mDb.update(channel, newValues, "id"+" = ?", new String [] {String.valueOf(id)});
```

}

But I am taking this error,

> 02-28 15:15:37.515: E/AndroidRuntime(5539):
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "check": syntax error
>   (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE Genelkultur2012 SET check=? WHERE
>   id = ?

**SOLVED:**

new codes

```
 ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
         newValues.put("tamam", true);
         mDb.update(channel, newValues, "id"+" = ?", new String [] {String.valueOf(id)});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CHECK` is a reserved keyword in SQL. Either rename the column or quote it in backticks.

Answer (score 1):

`newValues.put("check", true);`

You're trying to store **true**, a Boolean data type, which is not supported by SQLite. You'll instead have to store them in one of the following types:

1. **NULL**. The value is a NULL value.
2. **INTEGER**. The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.
3. **REAL**. The value is a floating point value, stored as an 8-byte IEEE floating point number.
4. **TEXT**. The value is a text string, stored using the database encoding (UTF-8, UTF-16BE or UTF-16LE).
5. **BLOB**. The value is a blob of data, stored exactly as it was input.

I'd suggest to store Boolean members as 0 or 1. More info here: http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: it looks normal.  there is no problem with "true"

Comment: Actually you were right because boolean makes some problem. I have changed boolean to 0,1 but as a text

Comment: So a boolean data type was indeed causing issues? And oh what type?